# how to make skype friendly links preview image tags

Tags: html, skype

I meet the same problem with @ddinchev and found the answer at:
[How to make Skype-friendly links (preview image tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588360/how-to-make-skype-friendly-links-preview-image-tags)
But with the link that I sent before, It still doesn't work. (New link is OK). Why's that? and How can I fix this problem?

Comment: then you should ask the questioner about the solution