# Branch link is not opening installed application while clicking on link shared to Skype

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have shared a branch link to Skype.But when I click on the link, it redirects to the App Store rather than opening my installed application.I have the link working for email,twitter etc ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: **unfortunately this is the expected behavior**.

Skype is [one of the apps that uses `SafariViewController`](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#apps-that-work-sometimes) so this is an iOS limitation from Apple. Links in Skype can't open other apps via Universal Links directly from the chat feed, and this is not an issue specific to Branch.

However, Branch does have a workaround available: our [deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews) feature sends users to a web landing page with an 'open in app' button. This *does* work, and is currently the best option available until Apple updates the Universal Links implementation to work properly with `SafariViewController`.

Comment: Also when I share an image and text via Skype, only the text and branch link appears ,not the image.The only image that appears is what we set in the Social Media Customisation settings of Dashboard.I have images appearing when I call "branchUniversalObject.imageUrl" for facebook sharing.Why not in Skype then?

Comment: It seems [you are not the first person to wonder this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588360/how-to-make-skype-friendly-links-preview-image-tags). I can't find any official Skype documentation about preview images, and this isn't a Branch-specific issue. Experimenting with image sizes might be one option

Comment: Hi @AlexBauer could you help in this matter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265931/branch-does-not-open-the-app-store-link
Thanks

Comment: @AlexBauer Is this expected for `Skype on Android` as well? It can not open branch links while the rest (such as Telegram or Twitter) work properly.